# Can I download straight to my PC?

Tags: laptop

I am a teacher - who is not very good with technology. I have heard about a new administration app called SchoolTool, which is only available on Ubuntu. I pressed download, and it is currently on my laptop. However, it's just sitting in my downloads, with a picture of a CD/DVD? If I click on it, it takes me to different documents with in the download, but I can't start it. I want to run it alongside my current windows 10. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read here: [How to install Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) to know how to install Ubuntu. If you downloaded an ISO file, you could burn it into a DVD disk, or a USB drive. I recommend the second one because is faster, and easy to setup. On windows you can use [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) or [unetbooting](https://unetbootin.github.io/) to burn the ISO file into your USB drive. Then enable the USB boot option in your BIOS to be able to boot into the live Ubuntu system. However, please check the link provided in the comment to obtain more information.